# DBPedia Live Api does not return all property types but only dbp and dct

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia, rdfs

I am querying dbpedia live api with this url http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Black_Hours,_Morgan_MS_493%3E&format=application%2Fjson-ld and it only returns properties with types with dbp and dct.

There are other properties with prefixes such as owl but in the response these are not included. Should I add something to the query in order to include these properties to the response?

Comment: In your link I see also foaf and rdfs. Fro example http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment .

Comment: Naybe it's not only dbp and dct, but clearly some properies in the about pae doesn;t show in the rquest.

Comment: I wanted to say owl bit Ive written rdfs I corrected it.

Comment: I don't get the problem. Which properties resp. facts exactly are missing from your point of view? there are also properties from namespace `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` in the resultset, so I'm not sure what you think is missing ...

Comment: alternatively, do `CONSTRUCT WHERE {<https://dbpedia.org/resource/Black_Hours,_Morgan_MS_493> ?p ?o}`

Comment: Well, when you entered https://dbpedia.org/resource/Black_Hours,_Morgan_MS_493 on browser, you can see a property named owl:sameAs. However, when you query via live API, this property is not listed in the response.

Comment: Construct query returned empty list by the way. And also I'd like to say that when I use a SELECT query instead of DESCRIBE to fetch owl:sameAs properties of some entity, it still doesn't return for the entitiy mentioned in the post. But it returns for e.g. Steve Jobs. And Steve Jobs is an older entity. Maybe it's because this Black Hours is so new that and updated lately and is not in the dataset used by Live API.